# Maximal ratio of probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given events $A, B_1, \dots, B_n$, all with positive probabilities, is there a name for the quantity
$$
\max_j \frac{P(B_j\mid A)}{P(B_j)} = \max_j \frac{P(A\mid B_j)}{P(A)}
$$
which measures the maximum amount of information that can be gained about $A$ if any of the events $B_j$ are observed?